# Deploying ncWMS2 WAR on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, gis, war

Am trying to deploy ncWMS2 WAR on Tomcat using Tomcat Manager on browser, but the deployed WAR is not starting. When I try to start it, I get this error : FAIL - Application at context path [/ncWMS2] could not be started.
What could be the solution?

Comment: what does the log file say happened?

Comment: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - Samuel [24/Nov/2020:19:36:31 +0300] "POST /manager/html/start?path=/ncWMS2&org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=0B8153B4A2A838571D107BF824A8DC25 HTTP/1.1" 403 3529

Comment: I would expect there to be some sort of error message when you restart tomcat or when you make that request, it will be in catalina.out or somesuch file (not access.log)